# jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile widgets conflict

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

In my application I have used the Dialog widget in jQuery UI but when I add jQuery Mobile the Dialog stops working.

```
$("#Global_Confirmation").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 'auto',
                modal: true,
                closeText: "",
                show: 'fade',
                hide: 'drop',
                title: settings.tital ? settings.tital : ''
});
```

I am referencing to the script files using Bundles.

Comment: There really isn't a great way of doing this since both extensions clobber the global `$.fn` namespace. Commonly you'd just to make sure to bundle them in sequence, with the one you actually want to use being last (it will overwrite the previous extension points). The alternative is implementing your own extension namespace policy. It may sound more robust but has a multitude of other downsides: unnecessary complexity, difficult maintenance, additional work with future changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jquery-ui dialog with jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435372/use-jquery-ui-dialog-with-jquery-mobile) and also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516857/circumventing-ui-dialog-dialog-conflict-with-mobile-dialog

Comment: @blgt I tried changing the sequence in bundle but it doesn't make any change. How do I implement a custom extension namespace?

Comment: Better to investigate why resequencing doesn't work. Anyway what I meant was in essence you'd load (or reload) the base jquery multiple times for the different extensions. This is **not trivial** and even if you can do it well I'd still recommend against it for the reasons above

Comment: I suggest You to use a JQM page with data-attribute "dialog". Anyway, if You stick with the UI-Dialog, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163312/4845566. Not 100% risk-free, however. The safest way I can imagine, is to download two custom versions of JQM and jQuery-UI with no-overlaps.

Comment: @blgt changing the bundled order fixed most of the issues but mouseover and mouseout events stopped working.